# Error starting "WordPress" stack - cannot calculate MAC address: hv_vm_create unknown error -85377023

Tags: wordpress, stack

I wondered if anyone could help me with the above on Wordpress? Trying to just start the application and this is what comes up and error shows. Please also see screenshots below to show exact reactions.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQx3p.png)

I have since found another article which says it could be because they don't currently support the new Apple M1 Chip? any ideas?

thank you in advance,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error and this is the solution:
on your terminal :

`cd /tmp`

`curl -LJO "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/hyperkit/hyperkit-testing-20210430"`

`mv /tmp/hyperkit-testing-20210430 ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit`

`chmod +x ~/.bitnami/stackman/helpers/hyperkit`

reference [Bitnami Comunity](https://community.bitnami.com/t/bitnami-wordpress-mac-os-11-3-big-sur-error-starting-wordpress-stack/94776/9)